# multiple custom-elements, but single class

Tags: javascript, class, custom-element

I want to create many different type of HTML classes.. normally you will extend a class and then register it..

```
class X1 extends HTMLElement {}
customElements.define('el-x1',X1)
class X2 extends HTMLElement {}
customElements.define('el-x2',X2)
........
class XN extends HTMLElement {}
customElements.define('el-xN',XN)
```

but this makes too many classes ..

What i think of doing is create one class with different .build() methods i.e.

```
class X extends HTMLElement {}
customElements.define('el-x',X)


X.prototype.build1 = function(){
    this.setAttibute(...)
    el = document.createElement(...)
    ...
    this.appendChild(el)
}


X.prototype.build2 = function(){ ... }
X.prototype.build3 = function(){ ... }
X.prototype.buildN = function(){ ... }
```

I want to define the build() methods later as I go ... closer to where I will use them. Thats why I would protype them

I will use them like this :

```
 x1 = new X()
 x1.build1()
```

this way I wont have to define new elements.

Is there a better way ?

---

```
 imagine having to build a <table> with hardcoded tags <td1>,<td2>, ... <tdN>
```

VS.

```
 only <td> cells but different content, and doing it in JS.
```

---

normal class based hierarchy + overriding a .build() method will work, but custom-elements require you to explicitly define() a tag for every new class

---

one of many dynamic grid-of-grids in specific 'state'. Everything is JS. Dont make conclusions.. the data is random ;)

All standalone elements have to be their own on the fly cell-pseudo-class, for which i use the prototype scheme above.

[image]

Comment: What would be the end benefit of creating multiple custom elements on the fly? And what will be the biggest difference between these elements?

Comment: they have different structure... but built using js rather .innerHTML

Comment: "*but this makes too many classes*" - well, you're also making too many custom html element types. Why would you even need different types if they all do the same things (are implemented by the same class)? What do you mean by "different structure"?

Comment: the basic class is in a lib and let say every prj that uses it creates a 2 cell-types with diff buttons, 1 cell-type caption, 2 cell-types of headings..etc.. all are cells with some content inside, built using JS. Every type is used 1-2 times, creating class is redundant. Have to inherit HTMLElement.

Comment: Sounds like you want to build a Class Hierarchy. What does ``class Build2 extends X2`` not give you?

Comment: You could create a single custom-element with some custom attributes for your structure. Then based on the values in those attributes render the structure dynamically. Maybe if you could shed some more light on what the end result should be, we could do a better job of helping you out.

Comment: @emiel thought about this, but need the declarations i.e. prototype functions to be close to the place where they are used. if i didnt have to define() new cust. elem. (where every el. has to have diff. name) then it would have been Base class which i extend and override .build() method.

Comment: @danny the problem is every el. has to have diff. name...  <el-x1 />, <el-x2 /> ... instead of just <el-x /> ... imagine in a table to use <td1>,<td2>,...<tdn>

Comment: @sten You still haven't explained *why* you think they have to have different names. A normal `<table>` also works just fine with only `<td>` elements (each of them having different children as contents).

Comment: requirement of ES5 for custom el., not me .. table didnt work well, so i'm using grids now

Comment: Why does it *have* to be `<el-x1>`, `<el-x2 >`, etc? Doing `<el-x type="1">`, `<el-x type="2">` would solve it. You can still call it from JS.

Comment: @sten ES5 does not make that requirement. And you shouldn't need to use ES5 anyway - any browser that supports custom elements also supports ES6+

Answer (score 1):

If you make a function to create the class and then automatically define it, you can do that. I'm not sure if there are any other ways to do that, although you can try using `customElements.define` with the same `class`.

A function that creates the class would look something like this:

```js
function defineElement(classToCopy, elmname) {
    let copy = class extends classToCopy {}
    customElements.define(elmname, copy);
}
```

It's still creating the classes, but at least you don't have to manual do it.

I wouldn't really recommend this, though.
What I would recommend is: inside of your original class, make a check for an attribute (called "mode," for example). If it's equal to (...), then use (...) build mode.